# How set value in SNMP / SNMP4J agent?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

How (what call) can I update a value of a variable in the MIB from within the agent? equivalent to using a PDU SETREQUEST call from the snmp manager. It is probably a very basic question - am new to snmp & snmp4j.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The question is too vague. What have you tried? Please give an example of what you want to happen.

Comment: have replaced this question with a new question: 'SNMP values not retained in MIB'